# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Returns 0 in SELECT INSERT Query - Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Below are my table data

```
TABLE Name: table_1
    id  value   created_date         
------  ------  ---------------------

TABLE Name: table_2
    id  value   created_date         
------  ------  ---------------------
     1  A       2021-12-17 17:22:55  
     2  B       2021-12-17 17:22:56  
     3  C       2021-12-17 17:22:57  
     4  D       2021-12-17 17:22:58
```

When I execute the below query in SQL Tool, I am getting FOUND_ROWS() value.

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (`value`)
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `value` FROM table_2;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

[image: SQL Output]

When I tried to execute in PHP Doctrine statements. It is not working!

```php
$statement = $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare("INSERT INTO table_1 (`value`)
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `value` FROM table_2 LIMIT 1000");
$statement->execute();

$statementFoundRow = $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
$statementFoundRow->execute();
echo $foundRow = $statementFoundRow->fetchColumn(0);exit;
```

**Output: 0**

But I am getting values when I am not using the INSERT Query.

```php
$statement = $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `value` FROM table_2 LIMIT 1000");
$statement->execute();

$statementFoundRow = $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
$statementFoundRow->execute();
echo $foundRow = $statementFoundRow->fetchColumn(0);exit;
```

**Output: 4**

**Can someone help me with 0-row issue?**

TABLE DATA for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `table_2` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `table_2`(`id`,`value`,`created_date`) VALUES
(1,'A','2021-12-17 17:18:15'),
(2,'B','2021-12-17 17:18:16'),
(3,'C','2021-12-17 17:18:17'),
(4,'D','2021-12-17 17:18:19');
```